# ¿Cómo poner una ruta predeterminada en un input type="file"?

Tags: javascript, eventos

El siguiente `script`, abre una ventana de dialogo de selección de archivos, del estilo `<input type=file>`

```js
function openFileOption()
{
  document.getElementById("file1").click();
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file1" style="display:none">
     <a href="#" onclick="openFileOption();return;">open File Dialog</a>
```

Sin embargo, necesito que esa ventana abra un determinado directorio por ej: `"c:\ArchivosEspeciales";` solo para consulta, no necesito que ejecute ninguna acción; sin embargo no encuentro la manera de realizarlo.

He visto que con esta instrucción es imposible hacer lo que quiero, sin embargo me imagino que debe existir algún código o `API` que lo realice.

¿Podría alguien indicarme que debo incluir?

A ver si me dan alguna idea. Necesito que el usuario almacene un archivo en el `path` que le indico. Dirán pues que busque la carpeta y lo guarde directamente, pero desafortunadamente lo están guardando en cualquier carpeta menos en la que corresponde.

Answer (score 3):

No puedes hacer eso porque expone un gran riesgo de seguridad. Eso conlleva a que el navegador pueda determinar si una ruta existe o no, lo que da mucha informacion aun hacker.

El navegador siempre abrira el filePicker en la ultima carpeta que el usuario haya utilizando anteriormente.

Ademas no hay forma de asegurar que el directorio existira en la maquina del cliente.

Comment: gracias...Ok!...entones a ver si me dais alguna idea....necesito que el usuario almacene un archivo en el path que le indico..Diras pues que busque la carpeta..y lo guarde directamente, pero desafortunadamente lo estan guardando en cualquier carpeta menos en la que corresponde

Comment: Lamentablemente con javascript ni HTML5 se puede. Por eso o entrenas a los usuarios para entiendan que eso es necesario guardar la información en esa carpeta o desarrollas la aplicación para escritorio.

Answer (score 2):

No se puede realizar por motivos de seguridad, ya que sería un importante agujero de seguridad y una gran referencia para alguien saber que tienes una ruta determinada en tu ordenador.

Por defecto se abrirá en la última carpeta que el usuario haya utilizado para subir un fichero.

De igual manera, si tu intentas obtener la ruta de donde se encuentra alojado el fichero que vas a subir, tampoco te deja por el mismo motivo, porque sería una gran brecha de seguridad.

En su defecto, te devolverá un `fakepath`, algo similar a `C:\fakepath\tuFichero`.

Aquí un ejemplo, sube un fichero y verás la ruta que te devuelve:

```js
document.getElementById('fichero').onchange = function () {
  console.log(this.value);
}
```

```html
<input id="fichero" type="file" value="fichero" name="fichero" required />
```

Comment: gracias...Ok!...entones a ver si me dais alguna idea....necesito que el usuario almacene un archivo en el path que le indico.Diras pues que busque la carpeta..y lo guarde directamente, pero desafortunadamente lo estan guardando en cualquier carpeta menos en la que corresponde

Comment: @ProfesorInformatica Lamentablemente, esto no lo vas a poder modificar, ya que es un tema de seguridad y está así hecho precisamente para que nadie pueda tocarlo. Igual con algún "hack" o alguna técnica avanzada se puede saltar, pero la desconozco actualmente, si no la hubiera añadido a la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitás hacer no se puede por motivos de seguridad.

Si estás lidiando con usuarios sin demasiados conocimientos informáticos, lo que sí podés hacer es poner unas instrucciones en tu página que digan que copypasteen la ruta y el nombre de archivo. Algo como:

1. Copie el siguiente texto en su portapapeles:

   ```
   c:\Windows\System32\drivers\archivo.dll
   ```
2. Presione el botón "descargar archivo".
3. En la ventana que aparece, pegue el texto en el campo "nombre de archivo".
4. Presione "guardar archivo".